# change endian of hex in bitstring unpack

Tags: python, unpack, bitstring

I'm using the module bitstring to unpack a 24 byte boundary file. I dont have control over the input file. The default interpretation of the module is big-endian apparently which is easy to fix when unpacking data types like int or float but some data I want to be represented as hex values. Using the unpack hex values it displays the incorrect byte ordering. Is there a fix for this? Example input: `D806` desired output: `06D8`

```
from bitstring import ConstBitStream
fp = ConstBitStream(filename="testfile.bin")
firstChunk = fp.read(2*8)
data=firstChunk.unpack('hex:16')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ordinary Python formatting on a little-endian integer interpretation.

Rather than a `read` then `unpack` you also can do both together:

```
print('{:0>4X}'.format(fp.read('uintle:16')))
```

This reads then next 16 bits from the stream, interprets it as an unsigned little-endian integer then formats it as four characters of hexadecimal, right-aligned and padded with zeros.